# Deep Cache? Changes I make on filezilla are successful but does not appear on my devices?

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache, filezilla

I have recently changed web host providers, (from 123-reg to SiteGround) and have a HTML website. Now when I make a change via FTP through Filezilla, it says upload successful however I cannot see the change on my computer. The changes are there however, as when I test it via kproxy.com I can see the changes. I have tried clearing my browser cache several times and this has not fixed the issue. The changes can not be seen on my ipad/ phone, and also cannot be seen on another friends laptop and phone either.

Does anyone know what the issue is here? I have been using Filezilla for a couple years now and the changes have always been instant and seen just via a page refresh.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried F5?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting any extension in your browser that could be hindering it e.g **AdBlocker**

OR

1. In your Chrome browser, open developers tools (CTRL + SHIFT + I).
2. Navigate to Application tab.
3. Choose Clear storage from the side menu
4. Hit Clear site data button.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the dev console to the network tab.  look at the request to see where the data is coming from.   it could be stuck in your disk cache and [to clear it](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More
3. Click More tools. Clear browsing data.
4. At the top, choose a time range. To delete everything, select All time.
5. Next to "Cookies and other site data" and "Cached images and files," check the boxes.
6. Click Clear data